# How to get the count and display only one row

Tags: sql

I've got 3 Tables:

```
tblCustomer
CustomerID  CustomerName
   1         Customer 1
   2         Customer 2

tblOrder
OrderID CustomerID  OrderTypeID LoanNumber
1            1            1      98513542
2            1            1      71283527
3            1            1      10268541
4            1            1      61258965

tblOrderType
OrderTypeID    OrderTypeName
   1             Purchase
   2             Rental
```

Now, I'm looking to return `CustomerID`, `CustomerName`, `OrderTypeName` and `OrderCount`, where `OrderCount` is how many of each order the customer has. I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT tblCustomer.CustomerID, tblCustomer.customerName, tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, tblOrder.OrderID
FROM tblCustomer 
INNER JOIN tblOrder 
ON tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblOrder.CustomerID
INNER JOIN tblOrderType 
ON tblOrderType.OrderTypeID = tblOrder.OrderTypeID
```

It sort of works. It gets all I'm asking for, except for the `OrderCount`, obviously. The result is like this:

```
CustomerID         CustomerName      OrderTypeName     OrderID
    1               Customer 1         Purchase           1
    1               Customer 1         Purchase           2
    1               Customer 1         Purchase           3
    1               Customer 1         Purchase           4
```

But what I'm looking for is this:

```
CustomerID         CustomerName      OrderTypeName     OrderCount
    1               Customer 1         Purchase             4
```

Now, I've tried adding `Count()` into the query at various places (`Count(tblOrder.OrderID)` for one), and I get an error that `tblCustomer.CustomerID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`.

This isn't a homework assignment. I just don't know a whole lot about sql and database interactions, since it wasn't taught in my school, and I've got a friend who's throwing scenarios at me.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use grouping and aggregation:

```
SELECT tblCustomer.CustomerID, tblCustomer.customerName, tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, 
count (tblOrder.OrderID) asOrderCOunt
FROM tblCustomer 
INNER JOIN tblOrder 
ON tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblOrder.CustomerID
INNER JOIN tblOrderType 
ON tblOrderType.OrderTypeID = tblOrder.OrderTypeID
GROUP BY
tblCustomer.CustomerID, 
tblCustomer.customerName, 
tblOrderType.OrderTypeName
```

You can't use aggregate functions without grouping everything that isn't aggregated.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. Still green and trying to learn more complex database interactions. This was a good start, I think.

Answer (score 3):

The error message does tell you the issue. Whenever you use an aggregation operator (`COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVG`, etc.), you have to tell the database how these should be aggregated together. You do this with a [`GROUP BY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) statement (the link there is for SQL Server, but it should generally apply to all database engines):

```
SELECT 
     C.CustomerID
    ,C.customerName
    ,OT.OrderTypeName
    ,COUNT(O.OrderID)
FROM tblCustomer C 
INNER JOIN tblOrder O 
   ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
INNER JOIN tblOrderType OT
   ON OT.OrderTypeID = O.OrderTypeID
GROUP BY
     C.CustomerID
    ,C.customerName
    ,OT.OrderTypeName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just add group by and count the grouped rows

```
SELECT tblCustomer.CustomerID, tblCustomer.customerName, 
  tblOrderType.OrderTypeName, tblOrder.OrderID, 
  COUNT(tblOrder.OrderID) as OrderCount
FROM tblCustomer INNER JOIN tblOrder 
  ON tblCustomer.CustomerID = tblOrder.CustomerID
INNER JOIN tblOrderType 
  ON tblOrderType.OrderTypeID = tblOrder.OrderTypeID
GROUP BY tblCustomer.CustomerID, tblCustomer.customerName, 
  tblOrderType.OrderTypeName
```